# Call child class method in parent by name

Tags: c++

How can I implement `invoke` function?

```
class Args {};

class NoSuchMethod {};

class Base {
        public:
                Args invoke(std::string name, Args a) {
                        //get method and call it or
                        //throw NoSuchMethod()
                }
};

class One: public Base {
                int q;
        public:
                One(int q_): q(q_) {};
                Args test(Args a) {
                        printf("One::test() -> q = %d", q);
                };
};

class Two: public Base {
                std::string s;
        public:
                Two(std::string s_): s(s_) {};
                Args test2(Args a) {
                        printf("Two::test2() -> t = %s", s.c_str());
                };
};

std::vector<Base*> objs = {new One(123), new One(321), new Two("ha"), new One(0)};

int main() {
        objs[0]->invoke("test", Args());
        objs[1]->invoke("test", Args());
        objs[2]->invoke("test2", Args());
        objs[3]->invoke("test", Args());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check out `std::function` and `std::map`.

Comment: I use std::bind and create static map and override invoke for all child's. Maybe can I storage methods in parent and don't override invoke?

Comment: If an object is of type `One` what do you expect to happen if you attempt to invoke a member function of `Two` that is not a member of `One`?    Also, your `main()` demonstrates that you don't understand indexing of vector elements - in C++, the first element in a `std::vector` has index `0`, not `1`.

Comment: I was wrong with the vector index. If class doesn't have doesn't have member `invoke` throw `NoSuchMethod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly call a method from a string.  You also cannot call a parent method from a base method if the base method doesn't have access to what type it is.

One way you could achieve this is to set up a map containing functions that do what you need.

Something like (Code not compiled, but it should give you an idea):

```
    class Base {
            public:
                    Args invoke(std::string name, Args a) {
                            auto foundMethod = methods_.find(name);

                            if (foundMethod == methods_.end())
                            {
                                    throw NoSuchMethod();
                            }

                            (*foundMethod)(a);
                    }
            protected:
                    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Args)>> methods_;
    };

    class One: public Base {
                    int q;
            public:
                    One(int q_): q(q_)
                    {
                            methods_["test"] = std::bind(&One::test, this, std::placeholders::_1);
                    };

                    Args test(Args a) {
                            printf("One::test() -> q = %d", q);
                    };
    };

    class Two: public Base {
                    std::string s;
            public:
                    Two(std::string s_): s(s_)
                    {
                            methods_["test2"] = std::bind(&Two::test, this, std::placeholders::_1);
                    };

                    Args test2(Args a) {
                            printf("Two::test2() -> t = %s", s.c_str());
                    };
    };
```

Comment: Lambdas are better than `std::bind`